# How Do You Write A Custom Java Comparator For A Specific String?

Tags: java, lambda, comparator

Hello I was wondering if somebody could help me with a little bit of code I'm stuck on. So I'm writing a custom comparator using lambda statements I want to do the following. If the names that return of .getName() equals to each other then I want to pick the one that is the String "Up" from .getDirection() (Its guaranteed one of them is "Up" in that case, the other is "Down"), else we will look at which one is alphabetically higher depending on the .getType().

So far I have this:
 `(x,y) -> x.getName().equals(y.getName()) ? //confused part : x.getType().compareTo(y.getType) );`

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If the names that return of .getName() equals to each other then I want to pick the one that is the String "Up" (Its guaranteed one of them is "Up" in that case) --> What is "Up" coming from ?

Comment: Let me edit my question I messed up.I left a part out.

Comment: Can you clarify? If the names of the two objects are equal, what fields are you comparing and how?

Comment: So we're comparing two objects of the same type. .getName() and .getDirection() return Strings. So if  x.getName()'s String is the same as y.getName()'s String then I will see if x.getDirection() or y.getDirection() is the String "Up". It is guaranteed only one is "Up". If x.getName() and y.getName() are not the same, then I will call x.getType() and y.getType(), and pick them alphabetically.

Comment: Ok you check if x.getDirection() or y.getDirection() is the String "Up". Suppose x.getDirection() is "Up". Now what happens?

Comment: Your answer and the other guy's answer are perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to get too greedy with terseness. Closures are nice, but the objective is not to write the least amount of code, it's to write only the code that's needed to get the job done in a way that's easily understood (well, most of the time anyway...)

```
(x, y) -> {
    if (x.getName().equals(y.getName()) {
        return "Up".equals(x.getDirection()) ? -1 : 1;
    } else {
        return x.getType().compareTo(y.getType());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created an example class, hope it can help.

```java
package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * @author jinleizhang
 */
public class ComparatorTest {
  static class Car {
    String name;
    boolean up;
    String type;

    Car(String name, boolean up, String type) {
      this.name = name;
      this.up = up;
      this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return this.name;
    }

    public boolean isUp() {
      return this.up;
    }

    public String getType() {
      return this.type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Car{" +
          "name='" + name + '\'' +
          ", up=" + up +
          ", type='" + type + '\'' +
          '}';
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car carA = new Car("NewCar", false, "type2020");
    Car carB = new Car("NewCar", true, "type2019");
    Car carC = new Car("OldCar", true, "type1990");

    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
    cars.add(carA);
    cars.add(carB);
    cars.add(carC);
    Collections.sort(cars, (x, y) -> {
      if (x.getName().equals(y.getName())) {
        return x.isUp() ? -1 : 1;
      }

      return x.getType().compareTo(y.getType());
    });

    for (var car : cars) {
      System.out.println(car);
    }
  }
}
```

output

```
Car{name='OldCar', up=true, type='type1990'}
Car{name='NewCar', up=true, type='type2019'}
Car{name='NewCar', up=false, type='type2020'}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot write this as a comparator.**

Suppose you have these objects:

- A1: Name: A Direction: Down Type: 1
- A3: Name: A Direction: Up Type: 3
- B2: Name: B Direction: Up Type: 2

According to your logic, A1 < B2 and B2 < A3 and A3 < A1. This is a violation of the *transitive property* of the general contract of comparator.

Comment: Yes seems to be. Any idea why OP wont get runtime exception stating violation? Is it removed after 1.8?

Comment: They will likely get an exception at some point. The sort algorithm reports a violation only if it happens to detect one, it does not go out of its way to find them.